# Deploy failing for a Ruby script

Tags: ruby, heroku, deployment

While trying to test upgrade to heroku-18, I managed to get the app setup and it (at least) was visually exactly the same as the original app. But while deploying, I tried `heroku open --app appname-heroku18` and it still did not work. When I check log I get `heroku logs --tail`. Also tried `heroku open --remote heroku-18` but got the same error. Can someone please help?
Not sure if this is enough information to be shared. Please let me know if there is any other information required.

```
 ›   Error: Multiple apps in git remotes
 ›      Usage: --remote heroku-18
 ›         or: --app mailpixscheduler-heroku18
 ›      Your local git repository has more than 1 app referenced in git remotes.
 ›      Because of this, we can't determine which app you want to run this command against.
 ›      Specify the app you want with --app or --remote.
 ›      Heroku remotes in repo:
 ›      mailpixscheduler (heroku)
 ›   mailpixscheduler-heroku18 (heroku-18)
 ›
 ›      https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku-18: Git push fails. Showing different versions of Ruby on push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404874/heroku-18-git-push-fails-showing-different-versions-of-ruby-on-push)

Comment: I have tried that solution as well and actually it worked. My apologies. It is deployed successfully but I did not realize until now that there is no interface to what I am deploying. They are mere scripts. Thank you for looking for a solution though. Closing this thread.

Comment: @HarshalKarande did you solve it? I have the same issue

Comment: In my case it was not a proble really. Because I did not have any UI for the app, it was not showing anything.