# Can't push/deploy to heroku because the ruby version is wrong?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, deploying

I'm trying to push to heroku but I keep getting the following error..

```
 The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     You are trying to install ruby-2.3.1 on heroku-18.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Ruby ruby-2.3.1 is present on the following stacks:
remote:  !     
remote:  !     - cedar-14
remote:  !     - heroku-16
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Heroku recommends you use the latest supported Ruby version listed here:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#supported-runtimes
remote:  !     
remote:  !     For more information on syntax for declaring a Ruby version see:
remote:  !     https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions
```

When I run ruby -v the version I have installed is ruby 2.6.3 which is higher than what the error is giving me. Any ideas?

I've tried updating it and everything but can't seem to figure it out!

Gemfile listed below

The ruby gem is uptodate but when I run bundle install and then push to heroku it seems to still be selecting the wrong version somewhere!
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

```
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

ruby '2.6.3'

gem 'sidekiq'
#for sidekiq ui
gem 'sinatra', github: 'sinatra/sinatra' #some dependency issue with rails5

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.5'

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '1.2.3'
end
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.4.2'
end

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'pry'
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

    group :development do
      # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%=               console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: Show the content of your `Gemfile`. It might be referencing ruby 2.3.1 there

Comment: It's been referencing 2.6.3 everytime :(

Comment: After you ran `bundle install`, what do you get if you run `ruby --version`?

Comment: @lurker 2.6.3. The one in the gemfile.

Comment: That is peculiar. You could try removing `Gemfile.lock` and redoing the `bundle install`. Then retry the push to Heroku.

Comment: @lurker Thanks ofr replying btw! I just tried that hoping it would work but same error feedback! :(

Comment: Here's a related Q&A that may help: [Heroku 18 git push fails showing different versions of ruby on push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60404874/heroku-18-git-push-fails-showing-different-versions-of-ruby-on-push)

Answer (score 0):

so i ran into exact problem. Heroku had upgraded its stack and i was getting the same error like your.
Solution:

1. Check what ruby version you have installed with command: `ruby -v`
2. Install the new ruby version with rvm command:  `rvm install ruby@latest`
3. If you don't have rvm installed please install it: here is the command for macOS. You might want to look up if you are using windows!
   `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rvm/rvm/master/binscripts/rvm-installer | bash -s stable`

- you might have to restart your terminal at this point.

4. Recheck your ruby version again... `ruby -v`
5. After making sure your ruby version is upgraded in system.. upgrade your gem file ruby version.
6. Run bundle update.
7. Commit those changes to master
8. Push your master to heroku

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue with ruby-2.7.8 version while deploying my application.

I have received below error

```
 The Ruby version you are trying to install does not exist on this stack.
 You are trying to install ruby-2.7.8 on heroku-22.
 Ruby ruby-2.7.8 is present on the following stacks:
 - heroku-20
```

Then, I ran this below code to change the stack

```
heroku stack:set heroku-20
```

After that, it got successful.

Update: Only warning it will show is "This app is using the Heroku-20 stack, however a newer stack is available"

For this you can use specific stack for specific versions of ruby.